# How do you move a part to the player's torso using an offset?

Tags: lua, roblox

I've tried switching from Vector3 to CFrame and it still hasn't been working. The best I've gotten is the part appearing like 10 feat in the air, this is what I have so far.

```
 local Dog = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("PetTesting")

local RunService = game:GetService("RunService")
local tweenService = game:GetService("TweenService")

local Petfollow = game:GetService("ReplicatedStorage"):WaitForChild("PetFollow")

game.Players.PlayerAdded:Connect(function(player)

player.CharacterAdded:Connect(function(char)
    wait(1)
    local dc = Dog:Clone()
    dc.Name = "Pet"
    dc.Parent = char
    local offsetCframe = CFrame.new(0, 0, 0)
    dc.CFrame = char:WaitForChild("HumanoidRootPart").CFrame + offsetCframe
    dc.Anchored = true
    dc.CanCollide = false
    dc.Transparency = 0 
end)
end)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use a bit of CFrame manipulation as described in https://developer.roblox.com/en-us/api-reference/datatype/CFrame. I am not sure if this is the right way of doing this, so please reply if this is incorrect.

```lua
local offset = Vector3.new(0, 0, 10)
local newCFrame = humanoidRootPart.CFrame * offset
```